# Reading the posted review and rating from Google review-action POST request

Tags: google-schemas

I am trying to integrate the review-action button in our review request mailers. Following is the schema used.

```
 <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",
  "action": {
    "@type": "ReviewAction",
    "review": {
      "@type": "Review",
      "itemReviewed": {
        "@type": "Product",
        "name": "Samsung Galaxy Duos 06-013"
      },
      "reviewRating": {
        "@type": "Rating",
        "bestRating": "5",
        "worstRating": "1"
      }
    },
    "handler": {
      "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
      "url": "http://dev.snapdeal.com/reviews/rateReviewGmailButton?pageId=215768&email=furqan8810@gmail.com&limitedAccessToken=97801e79-5d2d-42c0-ad88-8e6ac06ad032",
      "requiredProperty": {
        "@type": "Property",
        "name": "review.reviewRating.ratingValue"
      },
      "optionalProperty": {
        "@type": "Property",
        "name": "review.reviewBody"
      },
      "method": "http://schema.org/HttpRequestMethod/POST"
    }
  },
  "description": "We hope you liked Samsung Galaxy Duos 06-013 . Please tell us about it."
}
</script>
```

The review button appears in the email . However when the publish request is sent from the button the POSTed form data is something like this:

```
sma=%5B%22sma%22%2Cnull%2C%22msg-f%3A1470144207624023699%22%2C1402657061725%2C%220%3Aproduct%3A%22%2C%5B%220%3Aproduct%3A%22%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C%5Bnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C%5B%22Test%22%2C4%5D%2Cnull%2C%5B%5D%5D%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2C%5B0%2C%22product%22%5D%5D%2C%221467005e20072e93%22%2C%5B0%2C%22product%22%5D%5D&
```

Decoded form:

```
sma=["sma",null,"msg-f:1470144207624023699",1402657061725,"0:product:",["0:product:",null,null,[null,null,null,null,["Test",4],null,[]],null,null,null,null,null,[0,"product"]],"1467005e20072e93",[0,"product"]]&
```

The above x-www-form urlencoded data does not seem to have any pattern for us to parse/extract the "review" and "rating" data that is embedded somewhere inside this data chunk. 
Could you please help me in getting the posted data read inside my Spring MVC controller.